# Photos framework. requestImageForAsset can't return right imagesize

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios8

I'm using the method `requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:` to fetch an image from a PHAsset.

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(150, 200) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:options resultHandler:handler];
```

These codes works but the returned imageSize is not {150, 200}, but {300, 400}, which is the full size of the image. What can I do to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How should I explain this...

In code or Interface builder, we will specify screen size as (320, 568) for iPhone 5 screen but its actually (640, 1136) retina size.

So (150, 200) will give you (300, 400). If you want 150 x 200, try specifying a targetSize of (75, 100) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your targetSize is : CGSizeMake(150, 200) try changing it to CGSizeMake(300, 400)

Answer (score 0):

I think we should fix targetSize with Screen scale.

```
-(CGSize)fixTargetSize:(CGSize)targetSize{
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
return CGSizeMake(targetSize.width*scale, targetSize.height*scale);
}
```

so,if you use UIImageView,you got a fixed image,it's right to show.